# How can I add optional strings in my regex matcher?

Tags: java, regex

My regex: `https?://iam(.*).foo.com/v1/bar`

which works but I want the middle part to be more specific instead of just allowing anything. For example, these URLs should all match:

```
https://iam.dev.foo.com/v1/bar
https://iam.uat.foo.com/v1/bar
https://iam.foo.com/v1/bar
```

Is this possible through regular expressions?

Comment: This is fairly basic: `(foo|com)` and you need to escape the dots

Comment: `regex = "https://iam\\.(dev\\.|uat\\.)?foo.com/v1/bar";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
https?://iam(?:\.(?:dev|uat))?\.foo\.com/v1/bar
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOZIiN/1).

*Details*:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `iam` - a literal `iam` string
- `(?:\.(?:dev|uat))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `\.` - a dot char
  - `(?:dev|uat)` - either `dev` or `uat` string
- `\.foo\.com/v1/bar` - a literal `.foo.com/v1/bar` string. Note that dots are special regex metacharacters and must be escaped if literal dots are meant.